# Laravel Override Relationship's Select Statement

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

### Problem

I have a table called `releases` which holds two polymorphic relationships like the following and I am using it as a pivot table.

| Releasable_id | Releaseable_type | Releaser_id | Releaser_type | version |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 89 | App\Models\App | 3 | App\Models\Team | 1.0.1 |
| 89 | App\Models\App | 3 | App\Models\Team | 1.0.2 |
| 89 | App\Models\App | 4 | App\Models\Team | 1.0.1 |
| 89 | App\Models\App | 4 | App\Models\Team | 1.0.2 |
| 89 | App\Models\App | 4 | App\Models\Team | 1.0.3 |

When I go to select the related `Teams` for a given `App`, I get back duplicate results because the version number makes a given relationship unique.

```
App::find(89)
    ->morphedByMany(
        Team::class, 
        'releaser', 
        'releases', 
        'releasable_id', 
        'releaser_id'
    );
```

| teams (id) | Pivot |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 1.0.1 |
| 3 | 1.0.2 |
| 4 | 1.0.1 |
| 4 | 1.0.2 |
| 4 | 1.0.3 |

### Attempted Solution

I tried working around the default relationship by providing a new select clause then grouping by the team id.

```
App::find(89)
    ->morphedByMany(
        Team::class, 
        'releaser', 
        'releases', 
        'releasable_id', 
        'releaser_id'
    )
    ->select('teams.*')
    ->groupBy('teams.id')
;
```

When I print the SQL for the query above I get the following:

```
select `teams`.* 
from `teams` 
inner join `releases` 
    on `teams`.`id` = `releases`.`releaser_id` 
where `releases`.`releasable_id` = ? 
    and `releases`.`releaser_type` = ? 
    and `teams`.`deleted_at` is null 
group by `teams`.`id`
```

However, when I call `get()` on the relationship. The `groupBy` statement fails because Laravel adds additional select statements to provide pivot data.

```
`releases`.`releasable_id` as `pivot_releasable_id`, `releases`.`releaser_id` as `pivot_releaser_id`, `releases`.`releaser_type` as `pivot_releaser_type
```

See error below:

```
Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #10 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'mydb.releases.releasable_id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: select `teams`.*, `releases`.`releasable_id` as `pivot_releasable_id`, `releases`.`releaser_id` as `pivot_releaser_id`, `releases`.`releaser_type` as `pivot_releaser_type` from `teams` inner join `releases` on `teams`.`id` = `releases`.`releaser_id` where `releases`.`releasable_id` = 89 and `releases`.`releaser_type` = App\Models\Team and `teams`.`deleted_at` is null group by `teams`.`id`)'
```

### Question

How can I override the default select statement on a relationship query, or even better, how can I create a polymorphic many-to-many relationship which has two polymorphic types?

Comment: Before your query write this and try again: DB::statement("set sql_mode=''");

Comment: group by (teams.id, releases.releaser_id)

Comment: @GautamPatadiya This works. How does this compare to calling `distinct` on the relationship?  Also will this affect other queries?